# Extracting Organization ID from WhoIs Query

Tags: whois

I am trying to extract `OrgId` from whois query to detect malicious servers.

```
whois 69.59.28.19 | grep OrgId: | awk '{print $2}'
```

But for some IPs there are multiple `OrgId` entries.

```
whois 69.59.28.19

whois 208.115.113.93
```

What is the reason of this kind of double Organization information in `WhoIs` answers?

And which `OrgId` should be chosen to detect malicious IP owner?